# Есть ли способы как перенести текст на следующую строку кроме <br>?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Собственно заголовок и есть вопрос, существуют ли иные методы? В гугле по запросу переноса строки только br и выдает, но я не уверен насколько использование этого тега является актуальным на данный момент, существуют ли другие способы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `white-space: pre;`

```css
p {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<p>Собственно заголовок
и есть вопрос,
существуют 
ли иные методы? 
В гугле по запросу переноса строки только br
и 
выдает, 
но я не уверен насколько использование этого тега является актуальным на данный момент, существуют ли другие способы?</p>
```